# RapidJson parsing array of json

Tags: rapidjson

What to do if I have this kind of json? I'm using rapidjson

```
{[
    {
        "username": "A",
        "level": "1",
        "score": "1774"
    },
    {
        "username": "Ab",
        "level": "1",
        "score": "1923"
    },
    {
        "username": "M",
        "level": "1",
        "score": "1991"
    },
    {
        "username": "P",
        "level": "1",
        "score": "2030"
    },
    {
        "username": "Am",
        "level": "1",
        "score": "2044"
    }
]}
```

This will surely failed the assert.

```
rapidjson::Document doc;
doc.Parse<0>(message.c_str());
assert(doc.IsObject());
```

and how to extract the array if it doesn't even have a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid JSON. For JSON object, i.e. `{ ... }`, it should contains key-value pairs. Two solutions:

1. You can simply remove the out-most `{ }` to make it a valid JSON. Then the root will be an JSON array, and `doc.IsArray() == true`.
2. Add a key before the array, e.g. `{ "a" : [ ... ] }`. Then you can access the array by `doc["a"]`.